# Passing $_GET or $_POST data to PHP script that is run with wget

Tags: php, post, get, wget

I have the following line of PHP code which works great:

> exec( 'wget http://www.mydomain.com/u1.php  > /dev/null &' );

u1.php acts to do various types of maintenance on my server and the above command makes it happen in the background.  No problems there.

But I need to pass variable data to u1.php before it's executed.  I'd like to pass POST data preferably, but could accommodate GET or SESSION data if POST isn't an option.  Basically the type of data being passed is user-specific and will vary depending on who is logged in to the site and triggering the above code.  I've tried adding the GET data to the end of the URL and that didn't work.

So how else might I be able to send the data to u1.php?  POST data preferred, SESSION data would work as well (but I tried this and it didn't pick up the logged in user's session data).  GET would be a last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be very carefull when posting the whole POST data into command line. If you don't parse/check it properly, you script will be prone to code execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: The users themselves don't enter any of the data being POSTed.  It's all generated by my server.  So hopefully this shouldn't be too much of a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you have you would do this, probably using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
exec("wget --post-data 'a=b&c=d' http://www.mydomain.com/u1.php > /dev/null &");
```

However, I would be curious to know why you are choosing to use wget over cURL or, if the file is on the same server, calling it directly. It seems a bit clumsy to use wget for this.

Comment: Here's what's happening... u1.php performs updates to the mysql database.  An ajax script on the user's end updates the page to reflect those changes.  But because u1.php takes so long to execute, I want it running in the background to prevent the user experience from hanging.  Background script processes are a totally new thing for me, so perhaps what you're proposing might make more sense.  But u1.php can take 10 minutes to run so I'm using wget to allow it to run without causing hanging on the user's end if he wants to navigate to another page.

Comment: 10 minutes to run? Can you explain what?

Comment: It scans the company's IMAP server for particular kinds of messages.  But for users whose inboxes are particularly large, the scan can take awhile.  It has no problem pulling all the data but of course it can take a substantial amount of time for users who don't properly maintain their inboxes.

Comment: By the way, this code worked just fine for what I need.  I realized that I was trying to send certain characters that didn't work and that was causing my problem initially.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use cURL (if it's an option)? You can pass POST data very easy.

```
curl -d "your=postdata&more=postdata" http://www.mydomain.com/u1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the cURL implementation directly?

```
$c = curl_init('http://www.mydomain.com/u1.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURL_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_exec($c);
```

**EDIT:** To submit `$post_data`, you construct a string like a GET query string:

```
$vData = array(
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'zoid' => 'frob',
  'slursh' => 'yargh',
);

$post_data = array();

foreach ($vData as $k => $v)
   {
       $post_data[] = urlencode($k) . '=' . urlencode($v);
   }

$post_data = implode('&', $post_data);
```

Comment: In the above example, where and how exactly would I specify the different POST variables and their data?  Sorry, I've never used cURL before.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!  Will definitely get use out of this.